# Why does Typescript ignore tuple contents beyond known sizes?

Tags: typescript, types, tuples

Is there anyway to make Typescript not allow this?

```
type TwoItemTuple  = [string, string];
const uh: TwoItemTuple = ['a', 'b', 'a']
```

If not, what is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: What difference is there at runtime? It seems that all the type intends to guarantee is that there are at least two items, so you can safely call `uh[0]` and `uh[1]`. If there are actually more in your array, why not just ignore them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might also be able to try something like this:

```
type OnlyTwo<T1, T2 = T1> = [T1, T2] & {
    0: T1;
    1: T2;
    2?: never;
}

var x: OnlyTwo<number> = [1, 1]; // Okay;
var y: OnlyTwo<number> = [1, 1, 1]; // Error
var z: OnlyTwo<number> = [1, 1, undefined]; // Error
var o: OnlyTwo<number> = [1]; // Error
var b: OnlyTwo<number> = [1, 1, 1, 1] // Error

var s1: OnlyTwo<number, string> = [1, "a"] // Okay
var s1: OnlyTwo<number, string> = [1, "a", 1] // Error
```

As far as I can see, with that type, the only thing that can be assigned to it is an array literal with exactly two items of the correct type.

One concern is that you can use `push` and `pop` to modify these arrays, which would turn the actual value into something that doesn't adhere to the type anymore. Use with caution.

Answer (score 2):

Per the TypeScript documentation on tuples: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple (emphasis mine)

> Tuple types allow you to express an array where the type of a *fixed number of elements is known*...
>
> When accessing an element with a *known index*, the correct type is retrieved...
>
> When accessing an element *outside the set of known indices*, a union type is used instead...

Unfortunately for your case there is no way to enforce a maximum number of elements for the Tuple type, but there will be a minimum of two `string` elements and any other element must be a string. Even `uh.push(nonString)` will not work.

If you absolutely need to enforce the number of elements for the tuple you might consider using an Object type instead such as `type TwoItemTuple = { prop0: string, prop1: string }` although this would *not* have the properties of an array.

Note that TypeScript does not enforce type safety when using bracket notation; even `uh['foo']` will work.